# How to redirect on specific URL to another URL in NuxtJs app

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

For example, when the entered url is

`http://localhost:3000/course-details`

it should always redirect to `http://localhost:3000/courses`

I remember there was a way to do that but I forgot it.

Comment: What are your components structure + files used in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can handle this in the middleware of vue-page-component

**pages/course-details.vue**

```
<script>
export default{
  middleware({ redirect }) {
    return redirect('/courses');
  }
}
</script>
```

this can be handled by nginx too

```
location = /course-details {
  return 301 /courses;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@nuxtjs/router-extras](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) is a nice library that will give you the possibility to make more customizable things router-wise, one of which is to redirect to another url.

`/pages/course-details.vue`

```html
<router>
{
  redirect: '/courses',   // this syntax also works >>  redirect: { name: 'courses' },
}
</router>

<template>
[...]
```

Otherwise, DengSihan's solution is a good vanilla solution.